# how to open a page in a new window in jsf with webflow after using evaluate

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, spring-webflow

in jsf with webflow, I need to use a link and when I click the link a new window should be appear but the url of the link is not static I have to reade it from the database and prepare it then use it for my link.

How can I do this thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h:commandLink target="_blank" value="Click here" actionListener="#{myBean.action}">
        <f:attribute name="attributeName1" value="attributeValue1" />
        <f:attribute name="attributeName2" value="attributeValue2" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

In myBean.java, inside getters you can have prepare statements and read from the database.

Refer to this link: http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html

Comment: I can not understand how h:commandLink get the prepared url ? is myBean.action should return string ?